# Confuse about some items in build.gradle file, android studio

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I have some bad confuse about the items in the **build.gradle** file, I have read the document [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html), cannot understand something, forgive me as a new in android. Here, take my file for example,
[image: my build.gradle]

#### First

As you can see, there is a red line in the dependencies element, it reminds me 
`the support library should not use a different version(23) than the complieSdkVersion(18)`. **BUT**, this program can run prefectly! Shouldn't there be some errors??

**BUT**, another but, when I add some new activities, there happens to be 98 errors like this, 
[image]

And, I changed this `23.0.1` to `18.+`, the red line is also there but the new added activity is working fine, and the program can run normal again.

OMG, I'm totally confuse about this !

#### Second

I will explain why I need the compileSdkVersion to be 18 and the appcompat version is 23.
Firstly, I have import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and this required the compileSdkVersion to be 18.

Then, since I added the `ZJHttpClient` module, looks like the `complile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` appeared automatically, and I can't delete this line.

So, what should I do to solve this 'problem'(if it's a true problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, there is a red line in the dependencies element, it
>   reminds me  the support library should not use a different version(23)
>   than the complieSdkVersion(18). BUT, this program can run prefectly!
>   Shouldn't there be some errors??

when `compileSdkVersion 18` and support support library version is not 18+ then its show you ***warning***(the support library should not use a different version(23) than the complieSdkVersion(18)) ***not an error***.

> BUT, another but, when I add some new activities, there happens to be
>   98 errors like this,

when `targetSdkVersion 23` and dependencies library version is >= 23 then ***you must have to use `compileSdkVersion 23`*** and you are using `18` that's why its show you 98 errors. after that you changed dependencies library version 18+ all error resolved am i right?

***so when `targetSdkVersion 23` and dependencies library version is >= 23 like `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'` then you must have to use `compileSdkVersion 23`***

---

you Second problem: I can't understand better but I think below explanation solve you query.

if you app need `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` then its also include `support.v4` library [check here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/build.gradle).

when we use `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` then its include

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

so only `com.android.support:design:23.0.1` library include all above. so we don't have to use additional library if its include in another library

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I `changed dependencies library version 18+ all error resolved`. So, make the question simple: Sine using `18.+`, my program can run good except the **warning**, if I can ignore the warning? Would there be  any problem??

Comment: @KaKa: yes. ignore that warnings, you app works fine there is no issue. but if you want to use material design and any new future from android 5.0 and 6.0 at that time you have to update your support library to 23+.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Looks like the `buildToolVersion 23.0.2` and `targetSdkVersion 23` will be no use since the compileSdkVersion and dependencies library version are all 18, and finally the program has nothing new future higher than 18, am I right?